# Open local PDF file at a certain point

Tags: pdf, file-io, load, adobe

Thanks to a quick search on stackoverflow and google, I was able to find that we can directly open a PDF file from a URL at a certain point.

As explained below, we can do so using the "nameddest" parameter:
[How can I programmaticly open a pdf at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446614/how-can-i-programmaticly-open-a-pdf-at-a-certain-point)

However, all the links I read talk about opening the pdf file from a URL. What if I want to open the pdf file in my local file system at a given location. For example, instead of the following:
http://example.org/doc.pdf#nameddest=Chapter6 
say, I want to do this:
file:///D:/work/doc.pdf#nameddest=Chapter6

I tried the same, but it doesn't work. Any help/suggestions?

Regards,
Kapil

Comment: NB: Named Destinations are NOT Bookmarks! There is no way of opening a PDF to a certain Bookmark. This is no doubt a way to get you to buy the full version of Acrobat, which is the only way to create Named Destinations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you using the file protocol but you can achieve it by invoking Acrobat or Adobe Reader directly:

```
acrobat.exe /a "page=2" "c:\Binder1.pdf"
acrord32.exe /a "page=2" "c:\Binder1.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.....however I am trying to open the pdf from some other application in an automated fashion, and the application would not know the installed path for "acrobat.exe" or "acrord32.exe" on the system.