# Java Servlet: how to escape the pound character when setting response header?

Tags: java, http, servlets

My Java servlet includes the following line:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=myFile.pdf");
```

I need to include a named destination defined in the PDF file as part of the file name. Ideally, I could use the following:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=myFile.pdf#Chapter3");
```

but when I run it, the url in the browser shows `/path/to/myFile.pdf%23Chapter3` instead of the desired `/path/to/myFile.pdf#Chapter3`.

How to escape the # in "filename=myFile#Chapter3"? Escaping with \ gives a compile-time error. Escaping with &035; doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried `\\#`?

Comment: That's the correct thing for it to show in an address bar. Why are you concerned with a browser URL, shouldn't you be worried about a 'Save As' dialog?

Comment: @bmargulies that's a header, though, not an address bar (and why does it show as a URL at all I wonder?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing is valid. It's a filename, not a URL: it doesn't have a fragment part.

Comment: Using \\# is replaced with \@23 in the URL, and doesn't work to advance the document to the named destination. Why do I worry about the browser's URL? When the URL appears as `/path/to/myFile.pdf%23nameddest=Chapter3` the PDF file opens to page 1. If I manually replace the %23 with # in the URL and press return, the PDF advances to Chapter 3 page. I'm trying to download the PDF file and have it open to the location specified by the named destination. The # character tells the PDF reader that the named destination follows. If the # sign isn't in the URL, the named destination is ignored.

Comment: @EJP, see answer provided here, regarding the fragment part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446614/how-can-i-programmaticly-open-a-pdf-at-a-certain-point

Comment: @ggkmath That link is about URLs. This question is about the filename in the Content-disposition header. It's not relevant.

Comment: Got it. It just so happens this name shows up in the URL address, causing my confusion.

Comment: Leave out the #Chapter3. The purpose of putting a filename in Content-Disposition is to give the user a default filename to save this as.  You can't save files with a # in the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RFC 2616 defines that "the Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user requests that the content is saved to a file" so I don't think you can do what you intend to through your servlet. Maybe you will have better luck with some script in the pdf : you could imagine parsing its own name to dynamically set it at the right anchor at opening.

Comment: Perhaps it is a filename. I was hoping since it shows up in the URL that adding the #nameddest=... would implement advancing to the PDF named destination. Perhaps that's wishful thinking.

Comment: There's no 'perhaps' about it. It is a filename.