# Java - PDF Generation Framework

Tags: java, itext

I am using PDF documents for various purposes using iText library.
Its like one class per PDF document. In a way there are a lot of similarities among the classes and the same have been listed below:

1. The fields have (x,y) location
2. The field can be wrapped after some no. of words
3. A field can have a value which is a function of one or more parameters
4. Subsequent page of PDF has to kept same or different

I am thinking of doing this layout business through a XML file. Any thoughts or innovative ideas of solving this are welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212577/how-do-you-create-a-pdf-from-xml-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at PDFBox Library which is now in the incubator of Apache

Comment: I could not find a running example on their site.
It would be great if you could provide a example for understanding it.

Comment: try the internet wayback machine http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.pdfbox.org you should have some examples in their former site

Comment: It may not be a good idea to recommend the OP a toolbox that has no recent documentation.

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox is nice, Used it before and good good help from the developer. You might want to have a look at XSL:FO. It is an XML based formatting language that can output the result as PDF (and other formats) using Apache:FOP.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/download/)? It's a FOP engine that uses CSS files as styling, and has a Java API. It's not free though (apart from the free Personal License)

Answer (score 0):

[Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) supports using XHTML/CSS to create PDFs.