# How to generated an HTML or PDF report in SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have an enterprise SonarQube 7.9 server and I am running my SonarScanner using my Jenkins server. I am trying to generate a SonarQube HTML/PDF report from each project to be emailed out by Jenkins.

Has anyone does this before? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube Enterpise and above versions provide a way to generate PDF reports and send them to people. Copied from SonarQube [7.9 documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/):

- [Portfolios: Portfolio PRD Report](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/user-guide/portfolios/):

  > On a Portfolio Home Page, you can download a PDF overview of the Portfolio by selecting **Download as PDF** from the "Portfolio PDF Report" dropdown menu in the upper-right corner. This is really convenient, for example, if you're going into a meeting where you may not have access to your SonarQube instance.
  >
  > You can subscribe to receive a PDF by email by selecting **Subscribe** from the "Portfolio PDF Report" dropdown. You can set the frequency of the report at the portfolio and global levels to **daily**, **weekly**, or **monthly**. The default frequency is monthly.
  >
  > **Note**: You will only receive the PDF if the Portfolio is computed.
  >
  > Portfolios are created and edited in the global Portfolio administration interface: **Administration > Configuration > Portfolios**. For more information, see [Configuring Portfolios and Applications](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/project-administration/configuring-portfolios-and-applications/).
- [Portfolio PDF Configuration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/project-administration/portfolio-pdf-configuration/):

  > A user with administrative rights on a portfolio can configure email distribution of the PDF. From a Portfolio Home Page go to **Administration > Executive Report**.
  >
  > ### Frequency
  >
  > You can tune the email frequency of the PDF Report. The possible values are:
  >
  > - Daily: report is sent during the first portfolio calculation of the day (if any)
  > - Weekly: report is sent during the first portfolio calculation of the week (if any) from Monday
  > - Monthly (default): report is sent during the first portfolio calculation of the month (if any), starting from the first day of the current month
  >
  > ### Other Recipients
  >
  > If people without SonarQube accounts want to receive the PDF, you can feed the administrative "Other Recipients" field with their email addresses.

---

If sending them from Jenkins is a must, you have to implement it by your own:

- execute REST commands from Jenkins to SonarQube Web API - collect all interesting data
- convert collected data to PDF (read [How do you create a PDF from XML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/212577/4944847))

I don't know your requirements, but for me it sounds like wasting a lot of time to implement a feature on Jenkins which is available on SonarQube.