# Convert XML file to PDF using XSLT in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I'm trying to convert XML report into PDF using XSLT in a Node.JS application.

From what I found this can be achieved using JAVA [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212577/how-do-you-create-a-pdf-from-xml-in-java](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but i didn't found a javascript example.

Comment: With SaxonJS there is an XSLT 3 processor for Node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js. But for XSL-FO to PDF I think you need to call java (e.g. as a subprocess) to run Apache FOP.